# setting (or changing) GPU timeout on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, timeout, glsl, gpu, watchdog

If a WebGLSL shader is way too long to compile and execute on http://shadertoy.com/ , I totally loose the control of X and linux (I cannot even switch to the console). Only the mouse move, nothing else.

I know that on windows I can set a GPU timeout, but I don't find the equivalent tuning on linux (and googling tell me nothing about). help !

PS: this is not a CUDA question.

Comment: While this question is not *technically* off-topic here, it would almost certainly be better to ask over on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: ok, thans for the suggestion.